# AWS to local machine file sharing

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to connect it with SVN in aws ec2. It is showing Network timeout. After that i tried scp to transfer again it is showing the same error connection refused.  Then i tried AWS S3 ec2 copy command to copy the file from local machine to S3 bucket but again it is showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The approach which I use to move code or files from local server to ec2 instance is git.
It maintains my file changes with proper commit messages as well as a proper set of revisions or iterations I have done until now.